# NotImplementedError: Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor (gru_1/strided_slice:0) to a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

i am trying to create neural network but i don't understand why i am getting this error

```
model.add(GRU(units=16, return_sequences=True)) 
model.add(GRU(units=8, return_sequences=True))
model.add(GRU(units=4))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

Comment: Can you share the whole code or at least the minimum to understand the error. Can you copy the whole error message?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.